# Bootstrap link button not working on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've been developing a website for my sister the last few days. Last night we uploaded it to the live website and tested it on mobile devices. We noticed an issue where all the buttons aren't working. With further investigating we established that the buttons are tappable, but only on the far left of the button.

We also have this issue on the embedded soundcloud widgets when not using Google Chrome on mobile devices (soundcloud prompts you to listen to tracks on the mobile app when viewing the site on IOS and android default browsers).

The website is here: [www.harrirush.com](http://harrirush.com)

All my buttons are written like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" href="<<link goes here>>" role="button">Beatport</a>
```

I need to solve this, since it looks like around 70% of the websites users are android mobile devices.

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: can you give me more details? what OS/Browser did you use?

Comment: Google chrome for android HTC one M8

Comment: I actually just noticed that the problem is the social widgets on the side of every page. They appear to be blocking the content under them (I used z-index to make sure the widgets are always over everything which may be the problem)

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question I worked out that the social widgets on the page were causing the problem. My solution was to build a "contact" page and remove the widget from the rest of the site.